Next.js operates outside workspace
I have a little typescript project using Next for client side and Nest for server side in different workspaces. However, when I run next build (in the client workspace), it recognizes an error (that isn't there because the tsconfig for the server is different) in the server workspace. This is my folder structure:
.
|-node_modules/
|-client/
| |-.next/
| |-src/
| |-next.config.js
| |-package.json
| |-tsconfig.json
|-server/
|-shared/
|-package.json
|-package-lock.json

The compiler output is:
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run build

> client@1.0.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Environments: .env
  - Experiments (use with caution):
    · externalDir

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types  ...Failed to compile.

../server/src/database/entities/users.entity.ts:3:2
Type error: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1.

  1 | import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Index } from "typeorm";
  2 |
> 3 | @Entity()
    |  ^
  4 | @Index("unique_username", { synchronize: false })
  5 | // CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_username ON users (LOWER(username));
  6 | @Index("unique_email", { synchronize: false })
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `build` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: client@1.0.0 
npm ERR!   at location: C:\Users\Jan\informatik\web-card-games\client

Process finished with exit code 1

./package.json:
{
  "name": "web-card-games",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Jan Thürmann",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "client",
      "server",
      "shared"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sharp": "^0.33.4",
    "ts-jenum": "^2.2.2"
  }
}

./client/package.json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.10",
    "flowbite": "^1.8.0",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.5.0",
    "next": "^14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "shared": "1.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}

./client/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

I know that I could modify the client's compiler options to prevent this error but I don't want the client compiler to read the servers code anyways.

Before building your Next app you must first compile your server to declaration files  and point the "types" field in your server package.json to the entrypoint. This will make tsc ignore compiling your typescript server files and just look at the declaration types in other treating it as any other external package.
